# Как перевести проект на UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8

У меня проект работает на windows-1251 (плохо знаю, по неопытности сделал на нем) все в этой кодировке базы данных, php скрипты и составляющие системы.

Хочу перевести весь проект в UTF-8.

С базами данных вроде бы понятно все, поменял кодировки и таблицах и основную кодировку и все нормально.

**Как мне файл перевести в UTF-8 чтобы потом не переписывать тексты в этих файлах, есть какие-то методы?** А то если я щас переведу будут везде `?????`

Comment: Копируете текст, переводите документ, вставляете текст. Это все  к примеру можно сделать обычным `NotePad++`

Comment: @And да это же гикнишся... Программами можно как нибудь все файл разом сделать?

Comment: Там не только файлы переводить нужно но и заголовки и web-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел сам ответ. Программа UTFCast Express https://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast-express.aspx все файлы перевела в UTF-8